# NGINX CONF with RAILS on LINODE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

This is my **nginx.conf** file

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
# server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/blog/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I tried to add SSL - I redeplyed and restarted NGINX and the server. I undid everything redeployed and it was back up.... Now I tried the same thing. Tried to add SSL it failed. Undid. Now server is down. [Here](https://github.com/Ruekompa/blog) is the github with revisions!

Answer (score 0):

Ran /etc/init.d/unicorn_blog start and restarted unicorn. It worked